# Что имеется ввиду в фразе из Google Python Style Guide: Access Control?

Tags: python

[Google Python Style Guide: Access Control](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#Access_Control)

> If an accessor function would be trivial you should use public
>   variables instead of accessor functions to avoid the extra cost of
>   function calls in Python. When more functionality is added you can use
>   *property* to keep the syntax consistent.
>
> On the other hand, if access is more complex, or the cost of accessing
>   the variable is significant, you should use function calls (following
>   the Naming guidelines) such as get_foo() and set_foo(). If the past
>   behavior allowed access through a property, do not bind the new
>   accessor functions to the property. Any code still attempting to
>   access the variable by the old method should break visibly so they are
>   made aware of the change in complexity.

Первая часть понятна: для обычного доступа не использовать сеттеры и геттеры с целью избежать лишнего вызова функций. C добавлением функциональности можно использовать property().

Вторая часть не понятна. Не могу уловить смысл. Что тут имеется ввиду?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смысл в том, что если вычисление аттрибута имеет заметную стоимость (CPU, другие ресурсы такие как сеть, диск), то не следует использовать property, которое для пользователя выглядит как простое обращение к аттрибуту: `obj.attr`. В таких случаях следует использовать явный вызов: `obj.get_attr()`, чтобы показать что получение `attr` не бесплатно.

Также, если в предыдущей версии, `obj.attr` работало, то руководство рекомендует сломать существующий код (и поддерживать только `obj.get_attr()` в новой версии), чтобы пользователь переосмыслил использование `attr` в свете новых требований на его вычисление.

Comment: Получается: 1) Если доступ к атрибуту тривиален, то просто обращаемся к нему: **obj.attr** 2) Если вычисление атрибута требует незначительных вычислительных или иных затрат, то используем _property_ и опять же обращаемся к атрибуту как **obj.attr**. 3) Если получение атрибута требует значительных затрат, то используем явные методы **obj.set_attr()** и **obj.get_attr()**, чем показываем, что получение/запись атрибута не бесплатно.     Получается так?

Comment: Верно. В общем случае так, если нет специальных требований.